# IsNumeric statement and a range

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hey everyone I am working on an assignment where i have to validate the user input data.  When asking my instructors if i can use a IsNumeric to validate a range between two numbers he just said yes and did not show me how.
Now I know you can validate using if statements , and i have several doing so  with a basic:

```
if hours < 0 then
   Messagebox("Please enter a value greater than 0" "Input Value to 
     low" messagebox.buttons retry/cancel) ''something like that
Elseif hours > 23 then
   Messagebox( "please enter a value less than 23"  "Input Value to 
   high" messagebox.buttons retry/cancel)
End if
```

I even asked him if i can use a AND in the if statement  to range the data. Again yes with no example

Example that i had in mind

```
If hours < 0 AND hours > 23 then
 '' continue processing
Else
    Messagebox("Please enter a Value between 0 and 23" "Input 
     value 
 out of range" messagebox.buttons retry/cancel)
End if
```

Comment: IsNumeric() is old. Integer.TryParse() or Double.TryParse() is the more common way to do this now.

Comment: I know there are better solutions for things like this but the instructors specifically said i had to do "old school and use what we have learned in the book." These other methods are mentioned in the book in  later  chapters but we cannot go beyond what they assign or we fail.

Comment: Please ask your instructor to relent and allow you to use modern programming practices. If you are industrious enough to find better methods and thoroughly read the associated documentation on line you should be rewarded. If the instructor refuses he should be reported to the administration.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your example you can try this:

```
If isnumeric(hours) then
    If hours < 0 AND hours > 23 then
        '' continue processing
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Input value out of range", 
                        "Please enter a Value between 0 and 23",
                        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel)
    End if
End if
```

Comment: IAmANerd2000 thank you for your input. I will give that a try! And let you know!

Answer (score 0):

`IsNumeric()` is old... modern practice would tend to use `Integer.TryParse()` or `Double.TryParse()`, depending on what kind of value you need. You can also use `CInt()` or `Convert.ToInt32()`, but when you know you start with a string, parsing is the best choice.

But what concerns me is you should also have `Option Strict` turned on, or at least `Option Infer`. Anything else is really poor practice. With that in mind, look at this code:

```
Dim hours As String = GetSomeValueFromUser()

If IsNumeric(hours) Then
    If hours < 0 Or hours > 23 Then 'a value can never be both negative *and* greater than 24
       '...
    End
End If
```

In any sensible project, that should be a compiler error, because it uses a string value (`hours`) as if it's a number. It *doesn't matter* that you checked with `IsNumeric()` first. If you're using `Option Strict`, as you should be, that's still an error.

This is much better practice:

```
Dim hours As String = GetSomeValueFromUser()
Dim hrs As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(hours, hrs) AndAlso hrs>= 0 AndAlso hrs <= 23 Then
        'code here
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Value between 0 and 23" "Input value out of range", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel)
End If
```

One additional thing here: **NEVER** declare a variable for Function without an explicit type known to the compiler. `Option Infer` can muddy the waters there somewhat, but generally the type of a variable should always be *known* and *fixed*.